# How to go to another page from the user's page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have a user page with the address `http://localhost:3000/users/10`, when I press the button on the other pages of the address, for example `http://localhost:3000/info`, browser makes a redirect to the page `http://localhost:3000/users/info`, and show error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=info`.How fix it?
My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  get 'static_page/index'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/new', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  match '/info', to: 'static_page#info', via: 'get'
  match '/faculty', to: 'static_page#faculty', via: 'get'
  match '/about', to: 'static_page#about', via: 'get'
  match '/contacts', to: 'static_page#contacts', via: 'get'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'static_page#index'
```

Answer (score 1):

You build relative links like this:

```
<a href="info">Info</a>
```

But instead you should build absolute urls like this:

```
<a href="/info">Info</a>
```

Your urls must start with an `/`. Same if you use the `link_to` helper: `link_to('Info', '/info')`

It would be even better if you give each URL a name like this:

```
get '/info', to: 'static_page#info', as: 'info'
```

Than you can use that name when you need to build a link:

```
link_to('info', info_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your "static" routes before `resources :users`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'static_page#index'

  # less verbose than match ... via: 'get' 
  get 'static_page/index' # do you really need this?
  get '/signin',    to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/new',       to: 'users#new'
  get '/info',      to: 'static_page#info'
  get '/faculty',   to: 'static_page#faculty'
  get '/about',     to: 'static_page#about'
  get '/contacts',  to: 'static_page#contacts'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  #...

end
```

Comment: nothing has changed, I think it is related to other

Comment: Did you try restarting your server? I tried this is out and the routing pattern does work. Is that your whole `routes.rb` file (its missing the `end` keyword)? Could also be something in your `application_controller.rb` file

Comment: yes of course I rebooted the server.
maybe you did not understand me?when I'm in http://localhost:3000/users/10 and I press the button "faculty", then I do not redirect to http://localhost:3000/faculty and at http://localhost:3000/users/faculty.But the page http://localhost:3000/users/faculty does not exist, and the browser displays an error.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Thought you where entering the url in the browser. In that case @spickermann is correct.